# T-SQL: Complex query to group and reverse-order linked child records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a parent table `CASES` and child table `UPDATES`. A daily routine logs each row from `CASES` to the `UPDATES` table. This means each `CASE` will have one and then multiple `UPDATES`.

**CASES**

```
CaseID  | CaseStatus | [other fields]
==============================================
PK(int) | Free text  | Free text...
```

**UPDATES**

```
UpdateID | UpdateDate   | CaseID  | CaseStatus | [other fields]
==============================================
PK(int)  | Date Entered | FK(int) | Free text  | Free text...
```

For this scenario, you can assume that `CASES` can be created but not deleted.

I need to sequence data from the `UPDATES` table in reverse-chronological order, so that all most recent `UPDATES` are sequenced first, then second-most recent `UPDATES` ordered second, and so on.

I need a query that returns a table like the following -

**QUERY-RETURNED TABLE**

```
SeqNo          | UpdateID | UpdateDate | CaseID | CaseStatus | [other fields]
=================================================================================
Calc'd (below) | [fields returned from UPDATES table]
```

The `SeqNo` field would somehow be calculated like -

```
(select CaseID, count(UpdateDate) as Total from UPDATES group by CaseID) -
(select Row_Number over (order by UpdateDate) as Step from UPDATES group by CaseID) +
1
```

So, if we have two `CASES`, and `CASE 345` has 4 `UPDATES` and `CASE 789` has only 2 `UPDATES`, the desired query would return -

```
SeqNo | UpdateID | UpdateDate  | CaseID | CaseStatus | [other fields]
====================================================================
1     | 9876     | 30-Jun-2013 | 345    | [free text...]
1     | 9875     | 30-Jun-2013 | 789    | [free text...]
2     | 9765     | 29-Jun-2013 | 345    | [free text...]
2     | 9764     | 29-Jun-2013 | 789    | [free text...]
3     | 9654     | 28-Jun-2013 | 345    | [free text...]
4     | 9653     | 27-Jun-2013 | 345    | [free text...]
```

**QUESTION** -- How would I calculate the `SeqNo` above and use it to return the desired results table?

Comment: Try generating the seqeunce number using `Row_Number() over ( partition by CaseId order by UpdateDate desc )` and then sort the results with `order by SeqNo, CaseId`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank You. `select (Row_Number() over (partition by CaseID order by UpdateDate desc)) as SeqNo, * from UPDATES order by SeqNo, CaseId`